# Pesachim 97a cruel death by starvation for rejected chatas animals

Tags: animals, korban, maseches-pesachim

[Pesachim 97a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.97a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) calls for a very cruel death by starvation in a cage of certain chatas animals who don't qualify for sacrifice. Other unsuitable animals are left to graze and be sold.  Is there any comment that this starvation death is blatantly against tzar baaley chaim?  If the answer is simply it's Halacha LeMoshe MiSinai, the question of gross cruelty still needs to be asked.

Comment: Do you have a better solution for what to do with these animals? "Grazing and sold" is a way of saying wait for a blemish so it can be sold, but that only is relevant if getting a blemish would allow sale. Here there is nothing to do or wait for.

Comment: People who sin are also sometimes given this 'treatment'. It seems for some reason it is better than killing them. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%98_%D7%94